# IOS — Facebook — Login dialog и Social Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-api, oauth

Скажите пожалуйста, правильно ли я понял, что Social Framework работает только с теми аккаунтами, которые указаны в Настройках? Предположим, что там не указан аккаунт фейсбука. Можно ли как-нибудь сделать в приложении поля для ввода логина и пароля, а затем авторизировать пользователя?

UPD: Принципиально важно в дальнейшем использовать SLRequest из Social Framework

Comment: Конечно можно, только вот не каждый пользователь захочет вводить свои персональные данные в неизвестно какую форму в каком-то приложении. Так что рекомендую открывать WebView и через него авторизировать пользователя, а из колбэков выхватывать токен, который собственно понадобиться для отправки данных.

Comment: Да, все верно, но если вы добавите в проект Facebook SDK, она сделает логин за вас даже если в системных настройках нет аккаунта, она откроет Safari и авторизует пользователя, вернется в приложение через URL Scheme

Comment: такая же фигня с вконтактом и твитером, если установлены приложения, они могут авторизовываться через них переходя по схемам.

Comment: Дело в том, что в данном задании мне нужно осуществлять запросы именно через Social Framework (SLRequest). А в SLRequest есть пропертя Account типа ACCount. Можно ли получить эту пропертю не из Настроек, а через токен? 
UPD: Нагуглил, что это возможно только с Твиттером. Или нет?)